# How to set dynamic URL to a webview?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am working on a quick prototype and not (yet) familiar with react.

I created an app and I want to dynamically inject a URL to my webview (react-native-webview) based on parameters (linking) passed when the app is opened.

```
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {

    state = {

    }
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    console.log(event.url);
    state = {
        url: ==> I will define it

      };


    //const route = e.url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
    //console.log(route);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        onLoadStart={(navState) =>
          this.setState({url: this.state.url})
        }
        source={{
          uri: this.state.url,
        }}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyWeb;
```

What I am doing on onLoadStart seems useless but I miss the logic, to be honest....

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the `WebView` component with the `this.state.url` so when the URL changes then it completely re-render the WebView instead of trying to refresh the URL.  `{this.state.url &&
    <WebView onLoadStart={(navState) => this.setState({url: this.state.url})} source={{uri: this.state.url}}/>
}`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I did tried to do setstate within my handleOpenUrl function but the URL is null when the webview is loaded even by copying/pasting your code...

Comment: Perhaps when it loads it has the value of null, how about you put a conditional null check to update the state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Deep-linking` from react-navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking

Then create your path dynamically with `prefix` and pass to your `WebView`.